# Visual Studio Community 2015 Installation (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to install:

- Visual Studio Community 2015 --> ISO
- On Windows 7 Professional SP1 (A fresh install)

During installation, the program is saying the following files are either missing or damaged. Any thoughts on how to fix this? There are alot of files. Am I missing some basic windows library that is causing this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

List of files either damaged or missing:

SqlDom.msi

AzureMobileServicesSdkV2.0.msi

DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi

SSDTDBSvcExternals.msi

TSqlLanguageService.msi

16ab2ea2187acffa6435e334796c8c89.cab

12613ba26e037e99a874a64c1084f880.cab

9126f6ff98d955951fe9323f4444c119.cab

05254f60ea43b4e3959b17cdb03268c0.cab

e10f8811d44b50885777f56f8272f66b.cab

07a57cdb41ba28cced14005f087267be.cab

ef4472fd7552490fd759075186ed2ec8.cab

ec9d39539c27e8cf5ad39bffce00c34e.cab

15bc5316e373960d82abc253bceaa25d.cab

5cf1d61a223a02ff2f52fe05f058d52e.cab

5509e4710313421be8d5e7cfbfde4d30.cab

1de82860db02f762c5f65a73daa31f3e.cab

0f5c9874ec8b03b3a2ef2148f76b34cf.cab

bfb5675f5755f6ddacec7ee0cc5328da.cab

SQLSysClrTypes.msi

SQLSysClrTypes.msi

SharedManagementObjects.msi

Comment: Looks like your ISO file is corrupted.

Comment: "I am trying to install:

Visual Studio Community 2015" - Why install an outdated compiler/IDE? Why not go with the most recent one?

Comment: "the program is saying the following files are either missing or damaged. Any thoughts on how to fix this?" - Get a new *uncorrupted* copy - obviously.

Comment: Where would I get an uncorrupted copy? I got this from Microsoft's website directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need an uncorrupted ISO file..  Scroll down to 2015 and download it from here:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: The file I am installing is from the website you've provided. I tried re-downloading and installing. Still has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify the integrity of your VS2015 Community, please use the [FCIV.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290/availability-and-description-of-the-file-checksum-integrity-verifier-u) to verify the hash of your ISO file. Any difference will indicate that your ISO file is corrupted. If so, please re-download the VS2015 Community from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/vs/older-downloads/).

BTW, the SHA1 of Visual Studio Community 2015 DVD(English): BAAD3CEBAB7A5834D8F78F7D02E4880C010F3BA9.